# How do I delete folders and files that were older than 7 days on the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to delete folders and its files were created longer than 7 days using the command line.

Comment: On which OS (Win, OSx Linux? I am assuming Linux but you know what they say about assumptions.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/55721-folder-delete-command-prompt.html

Comment: Im not sure how you'd do the 7 day part, but if your using OS X or Linux you can use the command: rm -rf /path/to/the/folder

Comment: wa c mahmoud. you want to create a script that delete files before the 7th day ? and in which operating system ?!

Comment: In windows, and the folders I want to be deleted named as: 200110001,20110002 .. and so on, just the folder start with "2011..." i want to delete

Comment: FGraviton, i want to delete the folder that created before more than 7 days

Answer (score 12):

#### *NIX

If you are using *nix and have *find* available this should do the trick:

```
find /the/directory/containing/files/to/delete -mtime +7 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

The flag `-mtime` is to check the modification timestamp of the found files. If it's above `7*24h` ago,
it will execute `rm /path/to/file`

**From the manpage for `find`**

```
-mtime n  
    File's  data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments  
    for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation  
    of file modification times.
```

---

#### WINDOWS XP & VISTA

I never work on windows though I got curious to see what command to be the equivalent to the above in a MS-DOS environment. I found [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days) here on stackoverflow.

The relevant command (copy+pasted from the previously linked thread):

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* -d <number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

#### WINDOWS 7

Syntax has changed a little therefore the updated command is

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* /D -<number of days> /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: Rm requires the -r flag to delete directories, if I remember correctly. (UNIX)

Comment: @Jon Oh, I didn't notice it was a requirement to delete both directories and files, I'll alter my post right away. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: And just to be sure, it should also use the -f flag, so -rf will always force a delete. (forgot that one).

Comment: @Jon I left that out on purpose to be honest, better safe than sorry! ;)

Comment: refp, thanks alot for your answer,"forfiles" will work in windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deal with space limit issue on a very large file tree (in my case many perforce branches), that sometimes **being hanged while running** the find and delete process -

Here's a script that I schedule daily to **find all directories with specific file** ("ChangesLog.txt"), 
and then **Sort all directories** found that are **older than** 2 days, and Remove the first matched directory (each schedule there could be a new match):

```
bash -c "echo @echo Creating Cleanup_Branch.cmd on %COMPUTERNAME% - %~dp0 > Cleanup_Branch.cmd"
bash -c "echo -n 'bash -c \"find ' >> Cleanup_Branch.cmd"
rm -f dirToDelete.txt
rem cd. > dirToDelete.txt 
bash -c "find .. -maxdepth 9 -regex ".+ChangesLog.txt" -exec echo {} >> dirToDelete.txt \; & pid=$!; sleep 100; kill $pid "
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/' -e 's/^./"&/;s/.$/&" /' dirToDelete.txt | tr '\n' ' ' >> Cleanup_Branch.cmd
bash -c "echo -n '-maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime +2 | xargs -r ls -trd | head -n1 | xargs -t rm -Rf' >> Cleanup_Branch.cmd"
bash -c 'echo -n \" >> Cleanup_Branch.cmd'
call Cleanup_Branch.cmd
```

Note the requirements:

1. Deleting only those directories with "ChangesLog.txt", since other old directories should not be deleted.
2. Calling the OS commands in **cygwin directly**, since otherwise it used Windows default commands.
3. Collecting the directories to delete into external text file, in order to **save find results**, since sometimes the find process has hanged.
4. Setting a **timeout to the find process by using & background process that being killed after 100 seconds**.
5. Sorting the directories oldest first, for the delete priority.